# Is there an alternative to usermod on MacOS?

Tags: macos, docker, server, gitlab, continuous-integration

I want to build a docker image natively on a shell runner:
So I've been trying to register a GitLab runner with a shell executor on my local (MacOS) to build and run a docker image using this link:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-the-shell-executor

I have to run this command: `sudo usermod -aG docker gitLab-runner`  to grant permissions to gitLab-runner.
However usermod doesn’t work on mac anymore, so I tried to follow a few StackOverflow links which told me to use sudo or dscl. None of them seem to be working.
The error I’m getting on the pipeline :

`mkdir: /builds/ht8y-6qs/0/webapp.tmp: Read-only file system`

Does anyone know a workaround?
Ps: I know the best way to do this would be inside a layer of virtualization but I still want to figure this out

Comment: Are you just out of disk space? That would be inside of the docker VM on Mac if this error is inside of a container.

Comment: Nope, I have plenty of disk space